# How do you write multiple conditions on if statements

Tags: c, if-statement

```
if (num1 == (1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9)){
      *some command*
}
```

does this sequence work, if not can you guide me masters. I'm a beginner

Comment: `num1 >= 1 && num1 <= 9`

Comment: No, that sequence does not work. It's the same as `if (num1 == 9)`. The commas in your code are acting as [comma operators](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma_operator). When you compile, you should get 8 warnings saying *"expression result unused"*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
if(num1 >= 1 && num1 <= 9) {
// Some code
}
```

`&& operator` will make sure `num1` should be between 1 to 9 including it (i.e. 1, 9). It will execute some code only if both the conditions are `true`.

Answer (score 2):

If the numbers you're testing for are in a continuous range, you can bound the value with greater than and less than (or equals):

For example, if you're testing if an `int` `n` is one of 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, you can do this:

```
if(n >= 1 && n <= 9)
{
    // Code
}
```

If, however, the numbers are not a continuous range you have no choice but to explicitly test every value. So, if you were checking if `n` was one of 13, 57, -3, 11, -66, 100, you could have to write it out completely (or use a `switch` statement or lookup table):

```
if(13 == n || 57 == n || -3 == n || 11 == n || -66 == n || 100 == n)
{
    // Code
}
```

Alternatively (only for integral types):

```
switch (n)
{
    case 13:
    case 57:
    case -3:
    case 11:
    case -66:
    case 100:
        // Code
        break;
 }
```

You may want to write a helper method in the latter case to make it more clear what you're testing for. e.g.:

```
if(IsAcceptableValueForTask(n))
```

Where `IsAcceptableValueForTask` returns an `int` representing the truth (`1`|`0`) of `13 == n || 57 == n || -3 == n || 11 == n || -66 == n || 100 == n`

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```
if (num1 == 1 || num1 == 2 || num1 == 3 || num1 == 4 || num1 == 5 || num1 == 6 || num1 == 7 || num1 == 8 || num1 == 9 ){
      //code
}
```

If you want to check between a range of numbers you can use

```
if(num1 >= 1 && num1 <= 9) {
    //code
}
```

You can also use `switch` statement for more convenience if the numbers are random and there are many conditions